# Python Pandas CParserError Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to read a .csv file

```
df = pd.read_csv('ChildCareCenters06252017.csv')
```

and then I get this error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 31 fields in line 3, saw 42
```

I have read the pandas docs and I have gone through other stack posts similar to this but no solutions have worked.

I am going to this link 
https://secure.dss.ca.gov/CareFacilitySearch/DownloadData
and then clicking child care centers and then saving that data and trying to read.

This is what the .csv looks like in TextEdit. 
[Header and the first couple school entries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YgGc.png)

Comment: you can skip those lines using `error_bad_lines = False` otherwise you're going to have to find the stray punctuation in your csv thats causing the issues

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the `.csv`, saved it as a `.xlsx` file, and then used `read_excel()` instead, which worked:

```
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\Users\\nickb\\Desktop\\CCC.xlsx"  # update accordingly

df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

---

```
print df.head()

     Facility Type  Facility Number  \
0  DAY CARE CENTER        197416900   
1  DAY CARE CENTER        191607790   
2  DAY CARE CENTER        197416698   
3  DAY CARE CENTER        304370894   
4  DAY CARE CENTER        384001195  
...
```